# Есть тут ошибка или нет?

Tags: python

Задача из Codewars. Почему-то считает код не правильным, хотя при тестовых вводах всё работает как надо.

**Задача:**

Учитывая n, возьмите сумму цифр n. Если это значение имеет более одной цифры, продолжайте уменьшать таким образом, пока не будет получено однозначное число. Ввод будет неотрицательным целым числом.

**Код:**

```
def digital_root(n):
    if n >= 0:
        n = str(n)
        z = 0
        for i in n:
            z += int(i)
        if len(str(z)) == 1:
            print(z)
        elif len(str(z)) > 1 or len(str(z)) < 1:
            digital_root(z)
    else:
        print('None')
```

**Пример тестов:**

```
16  -->  1 + 6 = 7
   
942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 + 5 = 6

132189  -->  1 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 8 + 9 = 24  -->  2 + 4 = 6

493193  -->  4 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 9 + 3 = 29  -->  2 + 9 = 11  -->  1 + 1 = 2
```

Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Нужно было задать функцию. Сайт, по сути, сам должен активировать функцию.

Comment: Решение попроще интересует?

Comment: Конечно! Я был бы рад!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if n == 0:
     return 0
m = n % 9
return m if m else 9
```

Comment: верно, только if тут лишний `0 % 9 == 0`

Comment: Для ненулевых чисел, кратных 9, результат будет 9, а не 0. Или вы что-то другое имели в виду?

Comment: А каким образом вычисление деления остатка получается такое? Я просто не совсем понимаю.

Comment: @MBo я имел в виду `if n == 0` не нужен так как `0 % 9` будет `0`

Comment: @Daniil Loban  Но если на входе 0, то и вернуть надо 0, а не 9

Comment: @биллшифр исключительно математика) *На 9 делятся только те числа, у которых сумма цифр делится на 9*

Comment: так и вернется ноль))) `ноль % 9` будет `ноль`  уж не знаю как написать)

Comment: @биллшифр сумма цифр числа по модулю 9 равна самому числу по модулю 9. На примере трехзначного abc = a*100+b*10 +c = (a*99+b*9) +(c + a + b)  левая часть делится на 9, а правая равна сумме цифр

Comment: @Daniil Loban  В текущем виде функция для значений n = 0, 17, 18 возвращает соответственно 0, 8, 9. Как убрать ифы, чтобы поведение не испортилось?

Comment: я не учел того что 0 может быть 9, в общем все правильно тогда

Comment: Я проверил и как оказалось моё решение тоже верно. Просто учить математику надо больше.

Comment: @биллшифр Да, оно верное, если не учитывать ненужную работу со строками. Просто на сайтах с такими задачами рано или поздно столкнетесь с тем, что решение в лоб не пройдёт по времени, нужно будет привлекать математику или хитрые алгоритмы.